# How do I get the highest close and lowest close values given a specific time range e.g. 1 Hour?

Tags: pine-script

In TradingView's Pinescript, how do I do it?

In Javascript my thought process could be something along the lines of:

1. Define array of close values in 1H chart e.g. `var a = [1,2,3]`
2. Get max of array e.g. `Math.max(...a)`

I'm confused on how I can do it in Pinescript

Comment: Use code here: http://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#how-can-i-track-highslows-for-a-period-of-time Change source for both highs and lows to `close`, and period to `"60"`.

Answer (score 0):

Can use `ta.highest(source, length)`

For example `ta.highest(high, 10)` will return the highest high for the previous 10 candles.

Can also use array.max -- more info on that at [https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_array{dot}max](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_array%7Bdot%7Dmax)